# How to use Zurb Foundation reveal with open, opened, close, closed callback functions?

Tags: javascript, callback, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, dom-events

On zurb foundation's website at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php they listed some Options including

open:       callback function that triggers 'before' the modal opens.

opened:         callback function that triggers 'after' the modal is opened.

close:      callback function that triggers 'before' the modal prepares to close.

closed:         callback function that triggers 'after' the modal is closed.

But I have no idea how to use them with my modal.
I tried:

```
$('#myModal').closed(function()
{});

$('#myModal').trigger('reveal:closed')(
{});

$('#myModal').reveal.closed(function()
{});

$('#myModal').reveal().closed(function()
{});
```

I have Googled but found no hits. Anyone who can explain it or give me an example or provide a related link?

The suggestion given works, however
I have yet another closely related question for `reveal()`:

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="myModal2">Click Me For A Modal</a>);
```

I tried to add one attribute like `data-closeOnBackgroundClick="false"` That doesn't seem to work. What should be the correct syntax? Will it work for callback function as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `reveal` like you normally would, but include the name of the option and corresponding function as an object:

```
//Reveal the modal and say "Good bye" when it closes
$("#myModal").reveal({ "closed": function () { alert("Good bye") } });
```

Comment: I'm having trouble returning control to the parent view when the modal is closed. Perhaps you can help me. My question is here: stackoverflow.com/q/49161370/1735836

Answer (score 41):

The above answer did not work for me. Here's what worked (Foundation 4 and jQuery):

```
$('#myModal').bind('opened', function() {
  console.log("myModal opened");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me and made this cryptic message from the foundation docs clearer: "Reveal options can only be passed in during initialization at this time. However, you can bind to the open, opened, close, and closed events."

Answer (score 21):

**Event Bindings for Zurb Foundation Reveal -**

There are a series of events that you can bind to for triggering callbacks:

```
$(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});

$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});

$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});

$(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});
```

If you have multiple data-reveal used in single page as follows :

```
<div class="content reveal-modal" id="element-1" data-reveal>
<div class="content reveal-modal" id="element-2" data-reveal>
```

Then in this situations you can trigger callback same as explained above but with little modification as shown below :

```
$(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '#element-1[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});

$(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '#element-2[data-reveal]', function () {
  // your code goes here...
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble returning control to the parent view when the modal is closed.  Perhaps you can help me.  My question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49161370/1735836

Comment: In Foundation 6, replace: fndtn.reveal with zf.reveal, else this won't work.

Answer (score 15):

On Zurb Foundation v6, these events were renamed to `xxx.zf.reveal`:

> - **closeme.zf.reveal**   Fires immediately before the modal opens. Closes any  other modals that are currently open
> - **open.zf.reveal**  Fires when the modal has successfully opened.
> - **closed.zf.reveal**    Fires when the modal is done closing.

Source: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#js-events

#### Examples:

- Generic callback that will fire for all modals:

  ```
  $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
    console.log('This works');
  });
  ```
- Callback that will fire when a specific modal is opened:

  ```
  $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '#<ELEMENT-ID>[data-reveal]', function() {
    console.log('This works');
  });
  ```

Comment: On that note, you can also use this format:
$('#myModal ').bind('closed.zf.reveal', function() {
    console.log("myModal closed!");
});

Comment: @JustinJason The difference is that added examples will take care of forms added dynamically, while yours won't. Although that's a jQuery discussion

Answer (score 4):

Like meatrobot said, to get this working you want to bind to the modal with the action you are targetting. I got this to work:

```
$('#myModal').bind('closed', function() {
    console.log("myModal closed!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late but for the second part you add the attributes as a semi-colon separated list of values in the data-options attribute (tested with foundation 5), i.e:

`<div id="myModal"  data-options="close_on_background_click:false;" class="reveal-modal">`

And no, you cannot pass functions this way, i tried :)

Comment: for lightweight passing of options to a particular modal, this is definitely the way to go for foundation 5!  not for callbacks like the OP wanted, but config options.

Comment: You save my day. I cannot find that feature in Foundation Docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Foundation 5 and found that the reveal library triggers open, opened, close, and closed events. Just attach a handler to the event you want.

`$('#myModal').on([event], handler)`

You can also pass the handlers via the settings argument. 
Check this out: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js#L92

Answer (score 1):

The foundation 5 documentation specifies scoping of reveal events to the 'reveal' eventspace.  However, the actual modal events do not seem to fire consistently within this eventspace.  Removing this specification fixes the issue:

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn', '[data-reveal]', function() {
  console.log('This works');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In foundation 3.2.5 you should bind 'reveal:opened' like this:

```
$('#myModal').bind('reveal:opened', function() {
   console.log("myModal opened");
});
```

Regards, MarianoC.