# check if jquery reveal modal is active, do something

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to run some javascript ONLY on the condition that the reveal modal is active. The problem is that the methods I have tried have been True whether the modal is active or not. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I have tried :is visible method, also :active. I am using zurb reveal modal.

The html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <ul>
        <li>some list item</li>
        <li>some list item</li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--/myModal-->
```

The JS:

```
<script>
    if ($('#myModal:active').length){
        console.log('yes'); //always yes even when not revealed
    } else { 
        //do nothing
    }
</script>

//also tried if ($('#myModal').hasClass('someClass'))
```

**EDIT**

when active there is CSS of "visibility" : "visible", otherwise "hidden" so I tried the following, but it is not responding to the conditional. Any ideas why that might happen?

```
if($("#myModal").css("visibility", "hidden").length > 0) {
    console.log('is hidden');
} else {
    console.log('is shown');
}
```

This is the cookie code with [Zurb's](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) options for the reveal popup.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var tenYears = 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365 * 10;   //1000*60*60*24*15;//15days
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + tenYears);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString() +  ";path=/";  //encodeURIComponent +
    // Zurb's popup reveal modal
    $('#myModal').reveal({
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
        animationspeed: 100,                      
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems as though [this plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) activates a "open" class when clicked. So you should check the link like:

```
if($(".modal-link").hasClass('open')) {
    //do stuff when modal active
} else {
    //do stuff when modal not active
}
```

Better yet:

```
if($("#my-Modal").is(":visible")) {
    //you get the point
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Gone is my beautiful answer about `:active`, hopefully this simpler answer will help you with your real question, which basically is **how I can i register that the modal is open on the page, and perform some code based on this?**

The answer is [adopted from an answer on this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745505/how-to-use-zurb-foundation-reveal-with-open-opened-close-closed-callback-func), and also taken from the [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html):

```
$('#myModal').reveal({
    animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
    animationspeed: 100,                      
    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              
    dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal',
    opened:function(){
        console.log('yes');
        // magic
    }
});
```

This `opened` event will only fire when ... you guessed it ... the modal is opened, which is only called that first time they visit. If for some reason you have a continuous action that needs to be stopped upon closure of the modal, just bind to `closed`:

```
$('#myModal').reveal({
    animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
    animationspeed: 100,                      
    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              
    dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal',
    opened:function(){
        console.log('yes');
        // magic
    },
    closed:function(){
        // witchcraft
    }
});
```

This should be along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks PlantTheIdea for your response. In this case, there is no action for the user, the modal appears on first-time visit.

Comment: @bklynM well bloody hell haha. can you provide the code that the model uses to identify "first time visits" and then open? i can answer that far more easily.

Comment: @bklynM - edited my answer, should provide what youre looking for.

Comment: For some reason that isn't working, not tracing at all from inside that function, yet the modal itself works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: you can try using `open` instead of `opened` and `close` instead of `closed`... those functions exist as well.